# How to get all td[3] tags from the tr tags with selenium Xpath in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, web-crawler

I have a webpage HTML like this:

```
<table class="table_type1" id="sailing">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="multi_row"></td>
      <td class="multi_row"></td>
      <td class="multi_row">1</td>
      <td class="multi_row"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="multi_row"></td>
      <td class="multi_row"></td>
      <td class="multi_row">1</td>
      <td class="multi_row"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and tr tags are dynamic so i don't know how many of them exist, i need all td[3] of any tr tags in a list for some slicing stuff.it is much better iterate with built in tools if `find_element(s)_by_xpath("")` has iterating tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cells = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='sailing']//tr/td[3]")
```

to get third cell of each row

**Edit**

For iterating just use a for loop:

```
print ([i.text for i in cells])
```

Comment: how can i print it with pure text without the object weird code?

Comment: i used somehow the same: for cell in cells:
 print(cell.text) and it worked.thanks <3

Comment: what about if I want all tr tags except the last one in a table does xpath do tr[:-1]/td[4] ?

Comment: @iman_sh77 , try this one to get *third cell from each row (except the last one)* `//table[@id='sailing']//tr[position() < last()]/td[3]`

Comment: where can i find these techniques? the specific link of these kind o documents and oops it gave me an empty list when i tried that

Comment: and something i should say is that sometimes it just have one tr maybe that's why i get empty list

Comment: so how can i fix this problem i guess i should get all tr and then try to pull out td[3]?

Comment: @iman_sh77 , try this one `//table[@id='sailing']//tr[1]/td[3] | //table[@id='sailing']//tr[position() > 1 and position() < last()]/td[3]`

Answer (score 1):

Try following code :

```
tdElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id="sailing "]/tbody//td")
```

Edit : for 3rd element

```
tdElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id="sailing "]/tbody/tr/td[3]")
```

Comment: I know the XPath part the thing that I don't know is how to iterate on it and pull out the text of the third td

Comment: tdElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id="sailing "]/tbody/tr/td[3]")
you can get it with this code.

Answer (score 1):

To get the 3 rd td of each row, you can try either with xpath

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="sailing"]/tbody//td[3]')
```

or you can try with css selector like

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('table#sailing td:nth-child(3)')
```

As it is returning list you can iterate with for each,

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="sailing"]/tbody//td[3]')

for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

To print the text e.g. **1** from each of the third `<td>` you can either use the `get_attribute()` method or `text` property and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using *CssSelector* and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.table_type1#sailing tr td:nth-child(3)").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *CssSelector* and `text` property:

  ```
  print(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.table_type1#sailing tr td:nth-child(3)").text)
  ```
- Using *XPath* and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class='table_type1' and @id="sailing"]//tr//following::td[3]').get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *XPath* and `text` property:

  ```
  print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class='table_type1' and @id="sailing"]//tr//following::td[3]').text)
  ```